# : how to cook many crepes/pancakes “at the same time” *in a microwave*?

Tags: food

Making a single pancake **in a microwave** is easy: just take a Tefal round pan (no sharp corner no sparks), drop your dough, wait 2.5 minutes (it also work on any eating plates, but the first one is quite hard to unstick). But it's not really efficient in terms of time and energy. There should be a way to make several pancakes at once, and (optional) maybe even while using the same energy, or just a little more.

Using several layers of Tefal cooking plates won't be efficient since the microwaves don't pass through the metal.

So there are 2 challenges to solve:

1. Finding the right material to cook the crepe: it must be 1) food-safe (also under microwaves: so no plastic to be sure) 2) transparent to microwaves (or low loss). (What about using a thin sheet of glass? Cheap and safe.)
2. Finding the best vertical structure: what shape, how tall, how many layers? (Knowing that it should be rechargeable with dough quickly and also disassembled to clean it)

It's an engineering challenge, but that's the kind of hack that could really be a turning point for humankind.

Any advice is welcome.

PS: once again **the question is about cooking pancakes IN MICROWAVE**

**EDIT: the question was suddenly closed** (after some weeks/upvotes, and several answers) just when I dared to tell the people that their answer is off-topic. (I said to @virolino `what does it have to do with microwave cooking?` he replied `I do not like the tone of your question-comment`.

**If you also believe it was unjustifiably closed, please signal it** (eg. upvote my last comment).

Comment: Buy them already made and just use the microwave to warm them all at once?

Comment: Suppose it takes 9 seconds to drop the dough on the dish, place it in the oven, set the timer to 45 seconds, and (after) take out the food. To get a continuous output of pancakes and never have to wait, you need 5 microwave ovens.

Comment: @WeatherVane that was very creative! (But I'm sur you can find even better!)

Comment: The turning point for humankind -- in a downward direction -- was when we invented microwaveable pancakes instead of beautifully pan-made crepes ;)

Comment: @LukeSawczak true, it's actually a turning point when you live (and work) for years with another person in small appartement  (3 square meter habitable) under the roof with a wood beam just above your heating plate at 20 cm (and thus without cooking hood), and especially when you can't even open the windows because you get smoked by the chimney of your neighbor spitting toxic smoke from his woodstove in winter and from his barbecue in summer ;)

Comment: I seriously doubt that “a thin sheet of glass” should be classified as “safe”. Two points: thermal shock and fragility. Both can be achieved, but you need specific compositions and manufacturing methods.

Comment: And what is that Tefal plate you are talking about in your question?

Comment: @Stephie You are right for the regular glass. I was thinking of heat resistant glass plate like Pyrex. Tefal are metallic plates non-stick coated (they are use for cooking cakes)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks too much like an advertisement to a well known brand of cookware.

Comment: You talk of using metal plates in a microwave - although possible, that is unwise.  You say plastic isn't food-safe - clearly false.  Your question is based upon a series of false premises.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based upon a series of false premises and is unlikely to benefit the community.

Comment: Strangely, the question was suddenly closed (after some weeks/upvotes, and several answers) just when I dared to tell the people that their answer is off-topic. It tells a lot about the quality of this forum.  If you [who read this] believe it was also unjustifiably closed, please signal it (eg. upvote this comment).

Answer (score 0):

Note: I never even thought about using microwaves for cooking pancakes, so my answer will ignore that route (unfortunately).

In a home environment you are limited mostly by the... home environment. That means that it is difficult to run a successful business making huge amounts of pancakes. One of the biggest joys of cooking pancakes at home was the flipping - and I cannot imagine how one can successfully flip like 5 pancakes at once.

In a business environment, as well as at home, you might try the following hack. Use a big and flat (and thick) cast-iron board (that is significantly heavy, and you might need to have it custom made). Depending on the size of the pancakes you want to get, you can cook several pancakes at once. If you choose to make them rectangular / square, you can bake even more. The benefit of this hack is that one source of heat will be enough for all pancakes at once - the cast-iron is a very good heat-storage and heat-disperal material.

Comment: what does it have to do with microwave cooking?

Comment: @JinSnow: I do not like the tone of your question-comment. I answered your original question the way it was written - microwaves were just an example alternative of preparation. I will report your question for implying that using metals in a microwave is a recommended thing, while it is actually forbidden (dangerous) to use metals in microwaves.

Answer (score 0):

I very much doubt you can make crepes in a microwave. The essence of it is that you need to "sear" each side (not sure it's the best word) on a very hot plate. A microwave will instead warm the dough up gradually, or in other words, boil.

Crepes require very high heat, but they cook in seconds. This is not necessarily inefficient: I haven't done calculations, but in engineering this state of affairs (high power / quick action) is often the most efficient way of doing things.

The reason crepes need high heat is similar to why soldering iron is often heated to some >350°C while the solder melts at below 200°C: the dough cools the plate quickly (by rapid evaporation as well as by direct absorption), and it needs an excess of energy to stay hot. For this reason a good crepe pan is necessarily thick. I doubt a household microwave can make a thin sheet of dough absorb enough energy rapidly and evenly enough.

By the way, microwave is not even particularly efficient: a typical 700 W rated microwave actually consumes about 1.1 kW. In terms of efficiency, an induction cooktop must be the best for crepes (and most other things).

So, to answer the question: the practical way to make many crepes/pancakes “at the same time” is just to **have many crepe pans**. This, of course, hardly qualifies as "lifehack" because that's what most people do already.

How many one can handle depends on experience, and you'd need to time it and adjust the heat such that you'd have continuous action of pouring dough, flipping and removing crepes with minimum idle time. The thicker the pancakes, the more you can handle at the same time. For very thin crepes, I can manage four, and it's a practical limit at home anyway. Making 2-3 is more practical and comfortable if it's not a race.

Comment: @Zeus: "The thicker the pancakes..." Will you please explain what you wanted to say? Initially I thought you meant to "thinner", but now I think you have something else in mind.

Comment: @JinSnow: will you please explain the "better" to us? What do you know and we do not? We provided 3 answers to you, all of them quite clear that microwaves are not the best solution for pancakes, and all you do is patronize us - throwing rhetorical statements to us instead of being explicit.

Comment: @virolino, like with most things (e.g. steaks), the thicker they are, the longer they need to spend on the pan (or in the oven) to cook through. This makes it easier. With thin crepes, by the time you are pouring the 3rd or 4th one, the 1st one is ready for flipping. Dutch pancakes, you can probably make 60 at once :)